# How to redirect one page to another and then all remaining pages to a new site

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, friendly-url

I need to implement 2 redirects.

I want to redirect `example.com/subdir` to example1.com/subdir
Then I want to redirect everything else that remains on `example.com/` to example2.com/index.html

I tried the following but it does not get me to my solution:

```
redirect 301 /subdir https://example1.com/subdir
redirect 301 / https://example2.com/index.html
```

What ends up happening is everything redirects to `https://example2.com/index.html`

Thanks!

APPENDED

I need https://example.com/subdir to redirect to https://outlook.office365.com/owa/calendar/

Then, everything/anything else on https://example.com needs to redirect to a new site at example1.com

In other words, everything on example.com needs to redirect to a new condensed page at example1.com/index.html with the exception of example.com/subdir which needs to go to outlook/office 365.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following, written with shown samples. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(subdir)/?$ https://outlook.office365.com/owa/calendar [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://example1.com/your_single_page.html [R=301,NE,L]
```

Comment: "owa/calendar" is part of Microsoft Outlook and Office 365 site. So the first redirect needs to continue to go to https://outlook.office365.com/owa/calendar while everything else that remains needs to go the newly built and condensed single page at example1.com

Comment: @H.Ferrence, ok I have edited my rules now, could you please try them and let me know if those helps you?

Comment: Again, thank you for all your help @RavinderSingh13! I greatly appreciate the time you spent with me. But the latest did not work. I need to move on to other things so I'll solve this with meta redirects (yeah, I know that is the poor mans solutions and non-friendly) but I have other more pressing things to do as I am so you do as well. Best regards...I'm signing off.

Comment: @H.Ferrence, Awesome, very very happy that it worked for you, no need to regret on yourself, cheers and happy learning buddy cheers :)